# A few questions about Skinny Controller, Fat Model best practice - How to load methods and pass data from controller to model

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, model, controller

I'd really like some pointers on the best practice to follow when it comes to putting DB and business login into the model and having the controllers call the relevant methods.

I have a model and a controller for 'articles', see below. This code works fine but the way I have it working concerns me. I seem to be passing object all over the place (needlessly?) and there is lack of uniform to my method calls.

Hopefully the code is self explanatory and one of you geniuses can tell me everything I'm doing wrong and send back an example of how it should be done right!

Thanks for any tips!

FYI - The $article->tags field is comma-delimited 'keywords,like,this'

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Article;
use App\Models\Category;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    private $article;

    public function __construct()
    {
        
    }

    // SHOW ALL ARTICLES
    public function index(){
        // Fetch articles and paginate
        $articles = Article::getPublicArticles()->latest()->paginate(9);
        
        // Explode each article's tags to arrays
        $articles = Article::tagsToArrayFromMany($articles);

        return view('articles.index', [
            'articles' => $articles
        ]);
    }


    // SHOW SINGLE ARTICLE
    public function show(Article $article, $slug){
        // Increment the number of views
        $article->addView($article);

        // Explode this article's tags to an array
        $article->tagsToArrayFromOne($article);

        // Fetch other articles
        $other_articles = $article->getOtherPublicArticles($article->hex)->take(3)->get();

        // Explode each article's tags to arrays
        $other_articles = Article::tagsToArrayFromMany($other_articles);

        // Load the view
        return view('articles.show', [
            'article' => $article,
            'other_articles' => $other_articles
        ]);
    }
```

And here's the model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Article extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    // Set route key name
    public function getRouteKeyName(){
        return 'hex';
    }

    // Accessor for retrieving and formatting 'created_at'
    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value){
        return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['created_at'])->format('d/m/Y');
    }

    // Relationship to user
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    // Get all public articls
    public static function getPublicArticles(){
        return Article::where('status', 'public');
    }

    // Explode tags to arrays for all articles
    public static function tagsToArrayFromMany($articles = []){
        foreach($articles as $key => $article){
            if($article->tags){
                $articles[$key]['tags'] = explode(',', $article->tags);
            }
        } 
        return $articles;
    }

    // Explode tags to arrays for one article
    public static function tagsToArrayFromOne($article){
        if($article->tags){
            $article['tags'] = explode(',', $article->tags);
        }
        return $article;
    }

    // Add view
    public static function addView(object $article){
        $article->views = ($article->views + 1);
        $article->save();
    }

    // Get other articles
    public static function getOtherPublicArticles(string $hex){
        return self::getPublicArticles()->where('hex', '!=' , $hex)->orderByRaw('RAND()');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This question would most likely be more suited on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) but that aside.

My response is more of a comment than an answer, however, comments have character limits so leaving this here. This is also my opinion, there is a balance to be struck between perfectionism and pragmatism and developers have different opinions on where on the scale you should be in different situations.

There are a couple of books I would recommend for reference to guide you in future situations:

- [Clean Code](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/clean-code-a/9780136083238/) by [Uncle Bob](https://www.google.com/search?q=uncle+bob)
- [The Pragmatic Programmer](https://pragprog.com/titles/tpp20/the-pragmatic-programmer-20th-anniversary-edition/)

My reasons for recommending the above are that Clean Code provides goals to strive towards whilst The Pragmatic Programmer highlights that goals are great in isolation but not always productive.

We call ourselves programmers but we're more than that, we're problem solvers that just use code as our tool to do so. Our true goal is not to write beautiful code but to solve a problem. If we can simultaneously do both then fantastic but, a client doesn't care about the code we write they just want a solution.

My point being, aim to follow "best practices" but don't get too hung up on them and fall into the trap of [analysis paralysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_paralysis) and [bike-shedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality). Get something that works and then refactor where required later.

Anyway ...

Ideally a controller acts soley as a conductor between a request and response. It should determine where data should be forwarded and therefore which models or services to use. Business logic, shouldn't bleed into a controller.

Your `ArticleController` isn't horrific, however, it could probably be 'improved' a little. Both of your actions request data from your `Article` model then use the response to make another request to the model. Instead just combine those requests into a single request.

So for example refactoring:

```
$articles = Article::getPublicArticles()->latest()->paginate(9);

// Explode each article's tags to arrays
$articles = Article::tagsToArrayFromMany($articles);
```

To:

```
$articles = Article::publishedWithTags()->latest()->paginate(9);
```

You could do similar with your `show` method. Again this is just my opinion and you could 'optimise' it further by combining the `latest` call into your method if you wanted.

I am not sure why you have choosen to define all your methods as `static`, that doesn't seem necessary in my opinion. For querying your models, consider using [query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#query-scopes).

Additionally, rather than defining and calling an `addView()` method, consider using a [model event](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#events).

I don't know where you are in your journey, however, I suggest and recommend watching the [Laravel from Scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch) series. It covers a lot of common situations and suggested best practices when it comes to using the Laravel framework.